# Conctact ABI for pancakeswap (getReserves) works differently than for Uniswap

Tags: node.js, ethereum, abi, binance-smart-chain, uniswap

I try to use the same method to set the token price. For uniswap ABI everything works I use the method:

```
const getReserves2 = async (ContractObj) => {
// call getReserves function of Pair contract
const _reserves2 = await ContractObj.methods.getReserves().call();
```

but I have a problem with ABI pancakeswap and now I do not know why I try to use it but I get a message that it is not a function. What is the substitute in this case?

Comment: Pancakeswap pair contracts do implement a function called `getReserves()`. Can you share the pair contract address (along with the actual tokens addresses for the pair) that you're interacting with, as well as the ABI that you're using? Most likely the issue is an incorrect address or an incorrect ABI... Also, on which environment (mainnet or testnet) you're trying to perform the call?

Comment: const PAIR_ADDR3 = "0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16";
const PAIR_NAME3 = "BUSD/BNB";

Thank you for your help. The contract address tests a typical BNB/BUSD.

ABI I use from the contract tab on BSCscan . Maybe it is in the wrong format?

Comment: I start with : {
    "abi": 
+ (json from contract)
and at the end I add 
"bytecode": ""
}
, just like for uniswap (scrypt for uniswap works but for pancake it doesn't) , this is MAINNET

Comment: TypeError: ContractObj.methods.getReserves is not a function

Comment: Could the problem be that I am also using web3.eth for this purpose ? maybe I should use another library for bsc ?

Comment: You need to use just the `abi` part of the JSON. How do you get the JSON?